# Firefox keeps installing version 48 rather than developer edition

Tags: software-installation, firefox, ppa

I'm new to Ubuntu and I've been trying to follow the instructions of installing Firefox Developer Edition but it keeps installing Firefox 48.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

These are the steps I've been doing. I just get a message saying that Firefox is already the latest version.

However, when I do the following I see that version 50.0 is available in the list

```
   sudo apt-cache madison firefox

firefox | 48.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
       firefox | 48.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 | http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
       firefox | 28.0+build2-0ubuntu2 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
       firefox | 28.0+build2-0ubuntu2 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
       firefox | 28.0+build2-0ubuntu2 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main Sources
       firefox | 48.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main Sources
       firefox | 48.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 | http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main Sources
       firefox | 28.0+build2-0ubuntu2 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main Sources
       firefox | 50.0~a2~hg20160909r333109-0ubuntu1~umd1~trusty | http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora/ubuntu/ trusty/main Sources
```

Being new to this I am assuming I am doing something wrong or misunderstanding something. Can you help? Thank you.

Edit

Apt-cache policy output:

```
apt-cache policy firefox
firefox:
  Installed: 48.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Candidate: 48.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 48.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     28.0+build2-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

apt-cache policy

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-ubuntu-mozilla-daily-firefox-aurora,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Firefox Aurora builds,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-ubuntu-mozilla-daily-firefox-aurora,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Firefox Aurora builds,c=main
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://oem.archive.canonical.com/updates/ trusty-oem/public i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Canonical,n=trusty-oem,c=public
     origin oem.archive.canonical.com
 500 http://oem.archive.canonical.com/updates/ trusty-oem/public amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Canonical,n=trusty-oem,c=public
     origin oem.archive.canonical.com
 500 http://oem.archive.canonical.com/updates/ trusty-oem-sp1/public i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Canonical,n=trusty-oem-sp1,c=public
     origin oem.archive.canonical.com
 500 http://oem.archive.canonical.com/updates/ trusty-oem-sp1/public amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Canonical,n=trusty-oem-sp1,c=public
     origin oem.archive.canonical.com
 500 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ trusty-dell/public i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Canonical,n=trusty-dell,c=public
     origin dell.archive.canonical.com
 500 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ trusty-dell/public amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Canonical,n=trusty-dell,c=public
     origin dell.archive.canonical.com
 500 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ trusty-dell-dino2/public i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Canonical,n=trusty-dell-dino2,c=public
     origin dell.archive.canonical.com
 500 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ trusty-dell-dino2/public amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Canonical,n=trusty-dell-dino2,c=public
     origin dell.archive.canonical.com
 500 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ trusty-dell-biz-vivid-skl/public i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Canonical,n=trusty-dell-biz-vivid-skl,c=public
     origin dell.archive.canonical.com
 500 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ trusty-dell-biz-vivid-skl/public amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Canonical,n=trusty-dell-biz-vivid-skl,c=public
     origin dell.archive.canonical.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe Translation-en
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release o=Node Source,n=trusty,l=Node Source,c=main
     origin deb.nodesource.com
 500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Node Source,n=trusty,l=Node Source,c=main
     origin deb.nodesource.com
 500 https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet-release/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release o=dotnet-release trusty,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=dotnet-release trusty,c=main
     origin apt-mo.trafficmanager.net
 500 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-app-review-board,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Application Review Board PPA,c=main
     origin extras.ubuntu.com
 500 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=LP-PPA-app-review-board,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Application Review Board PPA,c=main
     origin extras.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner Translation-en
 500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Canonical,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Partner archive,c=partner
     origin archive.canonical.com
 500 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Canonical,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Partner archive,c=partner
     origin archive.canonical.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main Translation-en
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main Translation-en
 100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-backports,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe Translation-en
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse Translation-en
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=universe
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin us.archive.ubuntu.com
Pinned packages:
```

Comment: Edit the question including the  output of `apt-cache policy` command

Comment: I've added this info. I see that it does not list 50 in this output. What does that mean?

Comment: Oh, I said `apt-cache policy` only

Comment: My bad. Edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After inspecting the PPA, I have found that the binary build for trusty release  for version 50 has failed for all architectures. That means there is no binary package of version 50 yet.  See here https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-aurora/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=trusty.  Check the build status.

That's why you aren't being able to install it. You need to wait until it is fixed or build it yourself.

Comment: I've gone into Software and Updates and the Other Software tab and I've checked every checkmark box in the list. I then did the update and the install firefox and it is still latest version at 48. :/ Hmmmmmmm....

Comment: aha. found the answer. check the edit

Comment: Haha. Thank you. I've been trying to figure this out for hours. I guess I'll be waiting.

Comment: really. this confused me too! soo weird!!